# Google Autocomplete Filter is not working properly

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-api, google-places-api, autocompletefilter

I have a problem when I'm trying to get a list of results as user typing any  text. I'm using Google Places API TextAutoComplete service. I want to filter my results,for example, I want to get only ATM's in my result. I set type filter(Place.TYPE_ATM) to my AutocompleteFilter but it's not working properly, it's showing all(streets, cities, cafe's and etc.). My code:

```
filter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(Place.TYPE_ATM)
                .setCountry(MyApplication.getCurrentCountry())
                .build();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using the Google Play Service 9.4

Comment: I'm using 11.0.4 version. Is that can be a reason?

Comment: Is this the first time you are using the AutocompleteFilter ? Or was it working before?
If it's the firs time then I suggest u to try changing the play services version to '9.4' and check again.